Problem Getting Finance Data from Python Yahoo_Fin
I have been trying to get 'free cash flow' data for multiple stocks using Python. I have used the yfinance attribute: ticker.info['freeCashflow'] to do this however while this data is available for many stocks such as MSFT it is not available for many others such as GRMN. I have therefore tried to use yahoo_fin to get this info but have been unsuccessful.
Based on a web search I tried the following Python coding using yahoo_fin and received the errors noted:
import yahoo_fin as si
​
stock_ticker = "AAPL" 
stock_stats = si.stock_info.get_stats(stock_ticker)
free_cash_flow = stock_stats["Free Cash Flow"] 
​
print(free_cash_flow)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/zh/8wlzy7pn64l5hjmh151jpmfm0000gn/T/ipykernel_13547/3719391420.py in <module>
      2 
      3 stock_ticker = "AAPL"
----> 4 stock_stats = si.stock_info.get_stats(stock_ticker)
      5 free_cash_flow = stock_stats["Free Cash Flow"]
      6 

AttributeError: module 'yahoo_fin' has no attribute 'stock_info'



In an attempt to explore other solutions I played around with Yahoo_fin based on:
1)https://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/
2)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJ9pzD2ufj0&list=PL1EfVfbD6djHHxTzicLzdX5jzH0wEgDs7&index=1
3) and elsewhere
and was able to get stock historical price data but the finance query failed as indicated on the following Python run:
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
​
quote = si.get_data("NFLX")
print(quote)
​
flow = si.get_cash_flow('NFLX')
print(flow)
                  open        high         low       close    adjclose  \
2002-05-23    1.156429    1.242857    1.145714    1.196429    1.196429   
2002-05-24    1.214286    1.225000    1.197143    1.210000    1.210000   
2002-05-28    1.213571    1.232143    1.157143    1.157143    1.157143   
2002-05-29    1.164286    1.164286    1.085714    1.103571    1.103571   
2002-05-30    1.107857    1.107857    1.071429    1.071429    1.071429   
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
2024-11-19  839.750000  874.489990  839.159973  871.320007  871.320007   
2024-11-20  879.979980  890.599976  868.400024  883.849976  883.849976   
2024-11-21  883.929993  908.000000  877.239990  897.479980  897.479980   
2024-11-22  896.000000  906.000000  893.000000  897.789978  897.789978   
2024-11-25  902.049988  902.049988  864.219971  865.590027  865.590027   

               volume ticker  
2002-05-23  104790000   NFLX  
2002-05-24   11104800   NFLX  
2002-05-28    6609400   NFLX  
2002-05-29    6757800   NFLX  
2002-05-30   10154200   NFLX  
...               ...    ...  
2024-11-19    3814200   NFLX  
2024-11-20    4093800   NFLX  
2024-11-21    4511300   NFLX  
2024-11-22    3214000   NFLX  
2024-11-25    6004200   NFLX  

[5667 rows x 7 columns]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/zh/8wlzy7pn64l5hjmh151jpmfm0000gn/T/ipykernel_12525/4007971189.py in <module>
      4 print(quote)
      5 
----> 6 flow = si.get_cash_flow('NFLX')
      7 print(flow)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py in get_cash_flow(ticker, yearly)
    462 
    463 
--> 464     json_info = _parse_json(cash_flow_site)
    465 
    466     if yearly:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py in _parse_json(url, headers)
    371     html = requests.get(url=url, headers = headers).text
    372 
--> 373     json_str = html.split('root.App.main =')[1].split(
    374         '(this)')[0].split(';\n}')[0].strip()
    375 

IndexError: list index out of range



Does anyone have a view of what the issue is with getting free cash flow or finance data in general when using yahoo_fin.  Ultimately I want to get 'free cash flow' for a list of stock tickers.
